# How to create and build snappy apps ?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-core

I am very new to Ubuntu application development. I have to develop an application for snappy Ubuntu. Now I am confused about how to do it? So here are my few questions.

1. Which language should I use to develop snappy application ?
2. How to build that application? I am not able understand how does snap craft work or build an application?
3. I have written one simple application in QML for desktop and I want to test it on snappy Ubuntu. Is it possible to repackage it for snappy? if yes, how can I build it?

Comment: This might help: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/06/03/so-you-want-to-write-a-snappy-app/

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Which language should I use to develop snappy application ?

You can use any language that you can use to develop Linux software.
Don't understand Ubuntu Core Apps like Android Apps with a library as interface to the system.

A snapp (Ubuntu Core App) is a package of software that runs directly on a Ubuntu similar to Ubuntu Server.
The difference is that the app has everything in a private directory on the file system. It is jailed to that private environment and needs explicit permission to interact with other system components.

> 2. How to build that application? I am not able understand how does snap craft work or build an application?

Snapcraft ist a tool that reads a config file for your app that contains information of how to build the app and the location of its components.
It generates a snapp-file, that you can install on your Ubuntu Core system.

> 3. I have written one simple application in QML for desktop and I want to test it on snappy Ubuntu. Is it possible to repackage it for snappy? if yes, how can I build it?

I don't know for sure, but i think you will have to adopt it to use the "snappy infrastructure".